# What is the most efficient way to implement a findOrCreate pool in Scala?

Tags: scala, hashcode, equality

I would like to create a pool of objects of some type, let's say `Person`, implemented as follows:

```
class Person(val name: String, val email: String) { 
  val data = expensiveComputation(name, email)
}
```

and have a lookup method that looks like the following:

```
def findOrCreate(name: String, email: String): Person
```

This method should have the property that it always returns the same object for a given set of parameters to `findOrCreate`, creating it if it doesn't exist. Furthermore, I would like the objects to have cheap equality testing and hashing.

When these objects are initialised, some expensive computation is required, so I really want to avoid instantiating an object twice. In addition, the domain (actually sequence processing in bioinformatics) would make me instantiate each object 10-100 times if I didn't have a lookup facility, so memory costs are another compelling reason.

The best I have thought of is to create a mutable `HashMap` (to avoid GC overhead, since I will be creating a large number of objects) which maps the parameters to Person instances, and check for existence in the map on each call. In addition I would override equals with calls to `eq`, and leave `hashCode` as the default `AnyRef.hashCode` implementation.

Is there a better way of implementing this pattern?

Comment: just instantiate `case class Person(name: String, email: String)` and forget about the hash map altogether. I doubt you will get much out of this. Only consider another approach if you have hard proof that this performs too bad.

Comment: My question was too general. I have updated it with more detail. I do know from experience that I would waste a lot of CPU and memory if I create new objects for each input record I am parsing.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should just write your class

```
case class Person(name: String, email: String)
```

You get equality and hashing for free since it's a case class.

I don't think you really need to maintain a HashMap for that. The overhead of dealing with the HashMap, updating it, making sure it is thread-safe and always in consistent state, reclaiming unused instances, etc is probably not worth it for a case class with two string parameters.

Edit after question edit: Using a case class does not hurt, again you get `equals` and `hashCode` for free, but if you end up using a `Map[(String, String), Person]` you don't really need it since you have a tuple of strings for key. Using a HashMap is fine, but as I mentioned before: make sure your code is thread-safe (unless it is not a problem to have thread1 and thread2 create Person("bla", "bla"), you will still end up with only one instance stored in the Map) and you probably should also handle expiration to avoid a possible memory leak. I would explore a real caching solution like the one provided in the **Guava** library (or some scala equivalent).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The "Person" class here was only provided as a very general example of what I am doing - in reality it's more complicated and expensive. I've updated my question with more detail.

Answer (score 1):

From the design point of view you want to **create a companion object and hide your `findOrCreate` functionality behind the `apply` method**. This will make it look like you are creating a person object while still using your internal cache.

For actual cache, mutable map is sufficient, but Java or Guava equivalents can be used too.

```
case class Person(name: String, email: String) 

object Person {

  private lazy val cache = collection.mutable.Map[String, Person]()

  def apply( name: String, email: String): Person = {
     cache.getOrElseUpdate( (name+email).toLowerCase, createPerson(name,email))
  } 

  private def createPerson( name: String, email: String): Person = {
     // long operation here
  }
}
```

Then getting your Person is going to look like

```
   Person( name: String, email: String)
```